# VSFTPD link to a folder in root folder

Tags: ftp

I have just setup the basic stuff for `vsftpd`. I got that working fine with root use thats all. I have also stupidly installed something to the root user home directory which I would like another user to access can this be done and how?

So for example I have the root folder "/root/installedapp/plugins" and I want to create a user called pluginmod to only have access to that folder.

Can someone please and explain how this is possible?

Comment: The topic of having user accessible things in /root [came up on ServerFault recently in reference to a similar issue](http://serverfault.com/q/277752/40193). You might find the discussions there useful.

Answer (score -2):

Run the following commands as root.
First you need to add a new user.

```
# useradd -G ftp -b "/root/installedapp/plugins" pluginmod
```

Then set a password.

```
# passwd pluginmod
```

Then run chown to give ownership of the files to the user

```
# chown pluginmod "/root/installedapp/plugins/*"
```

After you restart vsftpd, you should be able to login to the user pluginmod over ftp with the password you set.

Comment: This answer will hit several gotchas, including any interaction between root and the pluginmod user will constantly create permission conflicts. Also it's a really bad idea to keep user accessible stuff in /root, and that should be mentioned in any answers that don't suggest a better way to do this.